# docker-compose build behind proxy. failed to solve: rpc error . dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io. on rockylinux image

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Frockylinux%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io on ipadress.

Answer (score 1):

In Docker, actions like pulling images are performed by the Docker daemon and do not use your shell’s environment variables.

When working behind a proxy, apart from configuring your proxy settings within your shell, you need to also configure them in Docker deamon.

To configure proxy in docker deamon, create directory /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d for Docker proxy settings config file. Then create /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf with the below contents. Replace `proxy_server_host` and `proxy_server_port` with your proxy server's host IP and port respectively.

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_server_host:proxy_server_port"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy_server_host:proxy_server_port"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

Apply the settings and restart docker with the below commands.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

You can confirm whether the settings have been applied with:

```
systemctl show --property=Environment docker
```

Comment: This worked well. Thanks ! 
Found it in the documentation later - https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#http-proxy:43644c643e7f8892a9f8a45991d7cd50

Answer (score 0):

before
`docker compose build --no-cache -progress=plain`

run this first:
`docker pull rockylinux:9-minimal`